# jquery post data after click

Tags: jquery

It has been a while since I used jquery. Basically I am trying to post some form data after a click. This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.pagination a').live('click', function() {
            $.post(this.href,
                { LikeOperation: $("LikeOperation").val() },
                { SearchTerm: $("SearchTerm").val() },
                function(result) {
                    $("form:first").submit();
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Unfortunately the data is not posted (post works though). Thanks!

PS:

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pagination a').live('click', function() {
    $.post(this.href,
    { LikeOperation: $("#LikeOperation").val(), SearchTerm: $("#SearchTerm").val() },
    function(result) {
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok I removed $("form:first").submit();, added # and combined the data. It works now! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot your # as part of your selectors

```
{ LikeOperation: $("#LikeOperation").val() },
{ SearchTerm: $("#SearchTerm").val() },
```

That's what is standing out to me right now.

Comment: Yeah the data is definatly send after I changed this. But the form is posted twice! Why is this?

Comment: Your success callback is making the second post with the $("form:first").submit();

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
$.post(this.href, // <-- first param
    { LikeOperation: $("LikeOperation").val() }, // <-- second param
    { SearchTerm: $("SearchTerm").val() }, // <-- third param (?!)
    function(result) { //<-- fourth param
        $("form:first").submit(); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now look at documentation: [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - third param is a function, not data. I think that problem lies in two things:
1. Use # in selectors: `#LikeOperation` - because there's no HTML tag like `LikeOperation`
2. Pass data as one object - instead of:

```
{ LikeOperation: $("LikeOperation").val() }, 
{ SearchTerm: $("SearchTerm").val() },
```

try:

```
{ 
  LikeOperation: $("#LikeOperation").val(), 
  SearchTerm: $("#SearchTerm").val() 
},
```